# How do I add two submit buttons to a Drupal 5 form?

Tags: drupal, drupal-fapi, drupal-5

I have two submit buttons on my form. One is the normal submit button that calls `my_form_submit` like-ah-so:

```
$form['fieldset']['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Show Applications',
);
```

I want to add another button that will submit the form, but call a different submit handler. Is there any way to do this? I have looked at adding the `#submit` property to an element like-ah-so:

```
$form['fieldset']['evil_plan'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Big Red Button',
  '#submit' => array('steal_formula_for_icantbeliveitsnotbutter'),
);
```

hoping to call the `steal_formula_for_icantbeliveitsnotbutter` function but no worky. When I click the Big Red Button the normal `my_form_submit` function is called, which sets back my plan to make millions off of a butter substitute. Who can shed some light on this dark mess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for Drupal 5, this is the only solution:

```
function my_form_submit($form_id, $form_values) {
  if ($form_values['op'] == 'Show Applications') {
    // handle 'Show Applications' submission
  }
  elseif ($form_values['op'] == 'Big Red Button') {
    // handle 'Big Red Button' submission
  }
}
```

same for `my_form_validate`.

in Drupal 6, this can easier be done with the newly introduced [custom #submit and #validate handlers for form buttons](http://drupal.org/node/144132#buttons).

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing it in the same submit function. Is there really no way to redirect it to a different submit function without going through the normal one?

Comment: +1, as this was the initial and correct answer fro Drupal 5! (Now if you just had mentioned that you checked the 5/6 difference, I wouldn't have interfered in the first place ;)

Comment: always trying to be as concise as possible :) tnx for the +1.

Comment: Yeah, premature selection of the correct answer, but I gave you a plus one. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** A closer check of the Forms API Documentation revealed that my initial answer below is valid for Drupal 6, but only partially valid for Drupal 5. Comparing the [Drupal 5 docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/5#submit_property) with the [Drupal 6 docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#submit-prop) shows that in Drupal 5, you can only register callback functions on the form itself - the '#submit' property of a button is just a boolean indicating that the button is to be handled as a submit button. So adding **'per button' callbacks is a Drupal 6 only feature!**

**For the given Question**, this means that there is only the if/elseif option suggested by ax, or the variation of registering two submit callbacks for the form, each checking if they are called for the right button (basically the if/elseif version, but using two separate callbacks).

---

(initial answer)

There are several mechanisms at work here:

1. Submit (and validate) callbacks can be registered for individual buttons, but also for the form itself (`$form['#submit']`). The ones registered for the form get called for every submit button, the ones registered for an individual button only for that one. (NOTE: Important Drupal 5/6 difference here, see edit below.)
2. The default form handling (submit and validate functions named after the form) works by Drupal automatically adding callbacks for those to the forms `'#submit'` and `'#validate'` arrays.
3. The registration uses arrays in order to allow for several submit/validate functions being called one after the other (in the same order they appear in the array).

So in your case, you could do the if/elseif switch suggested by ax, or you'd need to unset the 'global' callbacks for the form, moving it explicitly to the default submit button:

```
$form['fieldset']['submit']['#submit'] = $form['#submit'];
unset($form['#submit'];
```

(same thing for validate callbacks)

After that, your posted example for the Big Red Button executing the evil plan should work as expected ;)

Comment: That makes sense. So the $form['#submit'] (and validate) callbacks override the individual element ones. Is there a #validate callback I need to set as well?

Comment: Yup, validation follows the same mechanism, so if you need/use validation, you'd do the same for the validation callbacks.

Comment: Oups, just stumbled over a Drupal 5/6 difference in this context, see edit for details.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I'm on Drupal 6 for a while now and forgot about that difference. Also, in Drupal 6, the `$form['#submit']` would not *override* the button submit callback, but execute additionally.

Comment: what i was saying - i had checked on Drupal 5 vs. 6 :S

Comment: you might edit your answer putting the EDIT: at the top so someone looking for an answer doesn't try to implement the Drupal 6 solution for Drupal 5 before noticing it doesn't work.